# makefile target is newer than prerequisites but gets re-done

Tags: makefile

Running my target twice in a row it gets executed *twice*. This is wrong, since configure file *is* newer.

```
$ cat makefile
.ONESHELL:
configure: configure.www
    @REMOTE_FILE=$$(cat $<)
    @wget $${REMOTE_FILE}
    @tar -xf $$(basename $${REMOTE_FILE})
    @mv pspp-1.4.1/configure .
$ cat configure.www
https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/pspp/pspp-1.4.1.tar.gz
```

The `$$(cat <$)` happens *before* the `cp` that creates the configure file.

Comment: `mv`  does not change the last modification time. Check maybe whether your _new_ `configure` is really newer than its prerequisite (`ls -l`).

Comment: Ohhhh I see ... yes, indeed `configure.www` was more recent than pspp's `configure` file modification date. I'll post an answer "for future users" and reference your comment - if you want to add your own answer I will accept that over mine - thanks !

Comment: Happy to have helped. Your own answer is fine. By the way, you should maybe update your question: you wrote "_The `$$(cat <$)` happens before the `cp` that creates the configure file._" while it is not a `cp` but a `mv` that you use in your recipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting @Renaud Pacalet answer from the comments for future users:

Indeed, the `mv` instruction does not change the modification date, so the makefile really compares between PSPP's last modification date of `configure` and my own `configure.www` modification date. Since the latter is newer (and will remain newer) the target will keep getting executed.

```
$ stat configure | grep "Modify"
Modify: 2020-09-06 01:20:01.000000000 +0300
$ stat configure.www | grep "Modify"
Modify: 2021-05-05 10:11:43.891400412 +0300    // Newer !
```

I solved it by adding a final `touch` (no pun intended :))

```
.ONESHELL:
configure: configure.www
    @REMOTE_FILE=$$(cat $<)
    @wget $${REMOTE_FILE}
    @tar -xf $$(basename $${REMOTE_FILE})
    @mv pspp-1.4.1/configure .
    @touch $@    <----------------------
```